# Irreducible representation of $G=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: representation-theory

How can one prove that the irreducible representation of  $G=\mathbb{R}$ is $e^{kx}$? ($k\in\mathbb{C}$)
Thank you.

Comment: I found an answer myself. If a rep. of a group $G$ on a vec. space $V$ only has ${0}$ and $V$ itself as subspaces, then this rep. is irreducible. In this case, $e^{kx}$ is a rep. of $\mathbb{R}$ on the vec. space $\mathbb{c}$, which only has the subspaces ${0}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ itself.

Comment: Your comment is only part of an answer, as it only says the exponentials give irreducible representations (plural), not that every irrep is obtained in this way.

Comment: @whacka How am I supposed to show this?